# update_attributes not giving the errors Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code

```
if  user.update_attributes(user_params)
    render json: user , status: "success"
else
    render json: user.errors , status: "failed"
end
```

It updates the values if the object is correct . But let's say that email is duplicate then it does not goes in `else` condition . instead throws an exception.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry
>   'test@test.lo'

But as far i think . It should be a kind of thing which i could get like `user.errors.full_messages` .

I tried it using the following

```
if  User.new(user_params).valid?
user.update_attributes(user_params)
    render json: user , status: "success"
else
    render json: user.errors , status: "failed"
end
```

It gets into `else` condition but `user.errors.messages` are equal to `{}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to rely on model-level validation:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

If you rely on database-level constraints for validation, you're going to get exceptions upon write. You *can* capture those exceptions and attempt to turn them into a human-readable error message, but this isn't how Rails is meant to work.

If you want validation error messages, use validators in your models.

Comment: Great , Now this answer cleared one additional thing in my mind that if we're having any exception regarding database . We can handle it in Models . Thanks dear